# Mysterious NullPointer

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have been working on a project in which I take a file with Backus–Naur Form grammar notation and generate sentences with it. Here is the BNF file I am working off of:

```
<s>::=<np> <vp>
<np>::=<dp> <adjp> <n>|<pn>
<pn>::=John|Jane|Sally|Spot|Fred|Elmo
<adjp>::=<adj>|<adj> <adjp>
<adj>::=big|fat|green|wonderful|faulty|subliminal|pretentious
<dp>::=the|a 
<n>::=dog|cat|man|university|father|mother|child|television
<vp>::=<tv> <np>|<iv>
<tv>::=hit|honored|kissed|helped
<iv>::=died|collapsed|laughed|wept
```

Almost everything is working fine, with the exception of anytime the letter "a" is introduced via the  rule set. When that happens, I recieve the following error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at GrammarSolver.generate(GrammarSolver.java:95)
>           at GrammarSolver.generate(GrammarSolver.java:109)
>           at GrammarSolver.generate(GrammarSolver.java:116)
>           at GrammarSolver.generate(GrammarSolver.java:116)
>           at GrammarSolver.(GrammarSolver.java:51)
>           at GrammarTest.main(GrammarTest.java:19)

I have been trying to trace and locate the cause of this error, but have been unable to do so. So I am seeking the advice of someone with perhaps a bit more experience to show me where my bug is so I can understand what is causing it, and avoid replicating similar mistake in the future.

The code for my program is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class GrammarSolver {

    //Create output variable for sentences
    String output = "";

    //Create a map for storing grammar
    SortedMap<String, String[]> rules = new TreeMap<String, String[]>();

    //Create a queue for managing sentences
    Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();

    /**
     * Constructor for GrammarSolver
     *
     * Accepts a List<String> then processes it splitting
     * BNF notation into a TreeMap so that "A ::= B" is
     * loaded into the tree so the key is A and the data
     * contained is B
     *
     * @param       grammar     List of Strings with a set of
     *                          grammar rules in BNF form.
     */
    public GrammarSolver(List<String> grammar){
        //Convert list to string
        String s = grammar.toString();

        //Split and clean
        String[] parts = s.split("::=|,");
        for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
            parts[i] = parts[i].trim();
            parts[i] = parts[i].replaceAll("\\[|]", "");
            //parts[i] = parts[i].replaceAll("[ \t]+", "");

        }
        //Load into TreeMap
        for(int i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i+=2){
            String[] temp = parts[i+1].split("\\|");
            rules.put(parts[i], temp);
        }

        //Debug
        String[] test = generate("<s>", 2);
        System.out.println(test[0]);
        System.out.println(test[1]);
    }

    /**
     * Method to check if a certain non-terminal (such as <adj>
     * is present in the map.
     *
     * Accepts a String and returns true if said non-terminal is
     * in the map, and therefore a valid grammar. Returns false
     * otherwise.
     *
     * @param       symbol      The string that will be checked
     * @return      boolean     True if present, false if otherwise
     */
    public boolean grammarContains(String symbol){
        if(rules.keySet().toString().contains(symbol)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to generate sentences based on BNF notation and
     * return them as strings.
     *
     * @param       symbol      The BNF symbol to be generated
     * @param       times       The number of sentences to be generated
     * @return      String      The generated sentence
     */
    public String[] generate(String symbol, int times){
        //Array for output
        String[] output = new String[times];

        for(int i = 0; i < times; i++){
            //Clear array for run
            output[i] = "";

            //Grab rules, and store in an array
            lString[] grammar = rules.get(symbol);

            //Generate random number and assign to var
            int rand = randomNumber(grammar.length);

            //Take chosen grammar and split into array
            String[] rules =  grammar[rand].toString().split("\\s");

            //Determine if the rule is terminal or not
            if(grammarContains(rules[0])){
                //System.out.println("grammar has more grammars");
                //Find if there is one or more conditions
                if(rules.length == 1){
                    String[] returnString = generate(rules[0], 1);
                    output[i] += returnString[0];
                    output[i] += " ";
                }else if(rules.length > 1){
                    for(int j = 0; j < rules.length; j++){
                        String[] returnString = generate(rules[j], 1);
                        output[i] += returnString[0];
                        output[i] += " ";
                    }
                }
            }else{
                String[] returnArr = new String[1];
                returnArr[0] = grammar[rand];;
                return returnArr;
            }
            output[i] = output[i].trim();
        }
        return output;
    }

    /**
     * Method to list all valid non-terminals for the current grammar
     *
     * @return      String      A listing of all valid non-terminals
     *                          contained in the current grammar that
     *                          can be used to generate words or
     *                          sentences.
     */
    String getSymbols(){
        return rules.keySet().toString();
    }

    public int randomNumber(int max){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int returnVal = rand.nextInt(max);
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

and my test harness is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GrammarTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println();

        // open grammar file
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("sentence.txt"));

        // read the grammar file and construct the grammar solver
        List<String> grammar = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String next = input.nextLine().trim();
            if (next.length() > 0)
                grammar.add(next);
        }
        GrammarSolver solver =
            new GrammarSolver(Collections.unmodifiableList(grammar));
    }

}
```

Any help or tips will be greatly appreciated;

Thanks!

EDIT: The lines 95, 106, and 116 correlate to

```
94 //generate random number and assign to var
95     int rand = randomNumber(grammar.length);
...
105//Find if there is one or more conditions
106    if(rules.length == 1){
...
115 for(int j = 0; j < rules.length; j++){
116    String[] returnString = generate(rules[j], 1);
```

Comment: ah, that elusive NullPointerException. What is on line 95?

Comment: When I tried running it, it worked fine, can you post a sentence.txt that causes the error? The thing I do when I get NPE that helps is I add "assert ___ != null" in places to help isolate what specifically is coming in as null.

Comment: Tried to sync code and line numbers from the error message but it doesn't work - no match. Some other version of the file produced the error message. Please mark "line 95". (I guess it's this one: `int rand = randomNumber(grammar.length);`)

Comment: I added an edit to match line numbers with lines. Thanks so much for the help so far!

Comment: The grammar was coming back null for me, but that only happens when the sentences.txt file is not a properly formatted grammar.

Comment: You are posting a solution to a school assignment and receiving inappropriate help. I would appreciate it if edited your question so that you are not posting so much of the solution. Preferably, you would just delete the question. (I'm a TA for the class where this GrammarSolver assignment is given.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first step, I would make sure that

String[] grammar = rules.get(symbol);

doesn't return null. That will eliminate the suspected expressions like "grammar.length" and "grammar[rand].toString()". Next step would be to meticulously check all other dereferences for null.

Comment: I agree with @mazaneicha, before proceeding further validate variables against null's

Comment: Thank you guys very much. I was following this advice when I realized that "a" was getting passed through the recursion, and found the problem was actually stemming from the grammarContains method and using String.contains() which was reporting false positives because "a" could be found, so I redid the method and everything works great!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but I'd suggest you use an IDE with an integrated debugger such as [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/).

Using a debugger will give you valuable insight into the state of your variables at the time the exception happens. This will allow you to solve issues like this without waiting for us to try and figure out your code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Is there a place with a guide or tutorial to using Eclipse's debugger?

Comment: This [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeSitNPAExg) seems quite good.

Answer (score 0):

`rules` does not contain your terminals (a), it seems. You fail when trying `rules.get("a")`, as it returns `null`.

I also recommend using e.g. Eclipse for debugging - makes it easy to step through the stack frames when it crashes :-)